# Key not shown in IFormCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im trying to read values from a form that is posted back in an asp.net core application. The poco which is displayed has a Pictures Property that is of Type `List<PictureModel>`. So I thought, I could access each picture of the collection through an `IFormCollection` which is passed to ActionsResult in the controller. However, if a look at the keys in the collection, I only see Id and Title. The entry PictureModel_6 for example is missing. Why is this key missing?

View

```
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">

                <div>
                    <!-- As soon as one picture is selected in the fileopen dialog post the form back and reload the page with the added picture -->
                    <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                        Add Picture <input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" style="display: none;" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" value="uploadFile">
                    </label>

                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-lg-4" for="PicTitle">Pictures</label>
                </div>

                <div class="BilderVertikal">
                    @foreach (Models.PictureModel b in Model.Pictures)
                            {

                                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(b.DbBild);
                                var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
                                string formName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", b.GetType().Name, b.Id);


                        <img name="@formName" src="@imgSrc" />
                    }
                </div>

            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Model

```
public class MasterModel 
{
    public MasterModel()
    {

    }

    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value;  }
    }

    private string title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    private List<PictureModel > pictures;

    public List<PictureModel > Pictures
    {
        get { return pictures; }
        set { pictures = value;  }
    }
}

public class PictureModel 

    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value;  }
    }

    private byte[] dbPicture;

    public byte[] DbPicture
    {
        get { return dbPicture; }
        set { dbPicture = value; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string id, IFormCollection collection, IFormFile uploadFile)
{
    MasterModel m = new MasterModel();
    m.Title = collection["Title"].ToString(); //collection contains the key "Title"


    if (uploadFile != null)     
    {//Add Picture to the model without saving it

        PictureModel b = new PictureModel();
        MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
        uploadFile.CopyTo(target);                               
        b.DbBild = target.ToArray();

        m.Pictures.Add(b);

        return RedirectToAction(string.Format("Edit/{0}", m.Id));
    }

    foreach (var key in collection) 
    {
        if (key.ToString().StartsWith("PictureModel"))
        {
            //nothing found here
        }
    }       
}
```

**Solution**

Thanks to the great help of @Stephen Muecke I changed the code to this. This will create a key for each picture in the `IFormCollection`, which is no longer necessary, as the collection is also bound to the model nicely.

View

```
 <div >
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Pictures.Count; i++)

    {

        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Pictures[i].DbPicture);
        var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);


        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Pictures[i].Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Pictures[i].DbPicture)
        <img asp-for="Pictures.DbPicture" src="@imgSrc"/>
    }
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MasterModel _m)
```

The parameter _m now contains a filled `Pictures` property, hence no need for `IFormCollection`

Comment: You not generating any inputs relating to  a `List<PictureModel> Pictures` property! And you have not shown your model or controller method so impossible to understand what you trying to do.

Comment: Update Model and Controller. Basically, I want the user to be able to add pictures and/or change the item and save it to the database after the taks is finished. However, I need to store the model somewhere (not the database) to pass the changes along several edit actions.

Comment: What is `PictureModel`? And the only other input you have shown in you view is for a property named `uploadFile` and that is for a file input (which has a `value` attribute that makes no sense, and is submitting the form as soonas a you select a file which also makes no sense). And why in the world are you using `IFormCollection` instead if binding to you model (you method should be `public ActionResult Save(MasterModel model)`

Comment: I've posted the `PIctureModel` class as well, it is just a generic poco to store id and picture from the database.
The Postback is to reload the page with the added pictures shown. 
I used `IFormCollection`, because `Save(MasterModel _m)`returned an obejct where the `Pictures` Property was null.

Comment: Of course its `null` - your not generating a form control for each property of each `PictureModel` in your collection (and nor should you), so nothing relating to `PictureModel` is ever submitted back to the server

Comment: It seems like what you wanting to do is upload multiple files (edit the `Title` property and select one of more files)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thanks for your help so far! No, I don't want to necessarly want to upload multiple pictues (could be though). I guess I'm on a completely wrong path here. Could you point me to some tutorial that describes the best way to provide an input form, that allows to change a collection property of an object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162649/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mister-832).